# Optimizing image to fit max file size

Tags: javascript, terminal, applescript, photoshop, automator

I need to create a simple application that allows me to drag and image(s) onto and it will opimize the image ***below*** a certian file size.

I currently have a long drawn-out process in Photoshop where I have to save multiple images at once, reopen each, and export as the correct file size. The dimensions are always the same though. So 300x300 will always be below 40kbs, while the 100x600 will always be 35kbs.

Even if I'm running the images through Photoshop the same exact way. I was just hoping there'd be a faster/automated process but I'm having a lot of trouble finding one.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

*Note:* I don't want to change the image size (dimensions) only the file size (kbs).

Comment: Do you need this so other users/website visitors can freely upload the pictures and they would be automatically optimized on the server? Or do you just want to automate the whole process on your local machine and aren't primarily after creating a web application for this?

Comment: @RokSprogar thanks for the quick reply. Both/either would be cool, but I'm mostly just interested in it being a locally used "application". I'm just having trouble even finding the correct way to do this, whether that be a web app or a simple terminal script. After a lot of searching I decided someone else may have an idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that with **ImageMagick** which is installed on most Linux distros and is available for macOS and Windows. It only works for JPEG (because that allows trading image size for quality), whereas PNG does not - explicitly, at least.

So, say your image is 300x300 and particularly large at 161kB because it is incompressible random noise:

[image]

```
-rw-r--r--   1 mark  staff  161310 15 Feb 16:56 input.jpg
```

You can reduce it to your desired 40kB with this command in Terminal (or Command Prompt if under Windows):

```
magick input.jpg -define jpeg:extent=40kb result.jpg
```

And the result is 39kB:

```
-rw-r--r--   1 mark  staff   39119 15 Feb 16:58 result.jpg
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. I use it on my work computer and other programs wouldn't work but I was able to install Magick with Homebrew and bypass the security/firewall my work has. Thank you so much.

Comment: things are going great currently with this. I found out how to do both jpg and png to work perfectly as I'd like them based on your help; but now I'm running into trouble with GIFs. I'm trying to find the gif equivalent to "jpeg:extent=40kb". Just as the jpgs needed to be below 40kb, the gifs need to be below 200kb.Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

For local use, I'd set up gulp and use npm packages (any package that can do what you need to do) along the lines of:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-image-resize - to resize images

https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-imagemin - to compress images (I know you can use the size parameter to target the desired filesizes, at least for jpegs)

But showing you how to set everything up step by step would be beyond the scope of this answer, so let me just give you a rough outline of what you'd need to do:

- install node.js
- install gulp
- install the appropriate package managers
- configure gulp to grab the images from a specific folder and transform them manually or automaticaly into your desired "output" folder.

If you wanted to go down this route, I suggest you start learning more about gulp here:

https://gulpjs.com/